# Where I can find a translation of a Greek patent application?

Tags: patent-applications, translation, greece

I´ve been trying finding the translation into English of the Greek patent GR1004996B, by searching at WIPO patentscope, Espacenet and Google Patents, and didn't find it. There are just the original document and, in some cases, just the abstract in English.

Comment: The document on Espacenet is an image file. You might need to search for an OCR (optical character recognition) program that handles Greek.

Answer (score 1):

I was also unable to find a translation on the cited patent resources. What I did try is to first download the patent from Espacenet. This [pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12De9knDOtcAzvNshXxfmsk4sI8BGETKn/view?usp=sharing) is an image file so you need to convert it to text. I uploaded the file to [Convertio](https://convertio.co/ocr/greek/). This created a Word document with actual Greek text which is uploaded [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sA34Iu8xUHcZTVfeniA4IrE6J8PI7Aqy/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113918995543897677410&rtpof=true&sd=true) with some obvious although minor corrections. Evidently Convertio only does three pages for free. I then uploaded this file to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=el&tl=en&op=docs) and selected Greek to English. This resulted in a readable English translation, but again only for a portion of the text. Perhaps another OCR site would do a better job of converting the patent from images to actual Greek text or else pay Convertio to do the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same method as @Eric S until the translation part.

I used [the document translation service of DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator/files) which "performe[s] accurate" translations[1](https://www.deepl.com/translator/files) both according to the [research](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8494522/pdf/cureus-0013-00000017778.pdf) of independent medical researchers in the field of oncology between Japanese and English as well as according to DeepL's own [research](https://www.deepl.com/en/blog/20200206) involving double-blind tests with professional translators evaluating the quality of translations made by the system substantially better between main European languages than any other machine translation systems available for free.

The document translation by DeepL is [this .pdf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JYd_gHE7hQGKOdF227ENYhZwz4ceBDA6/view?usp=sharing) [2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8494522/pdf/cureus-0013-00000017778.pdf), I am certain that without using a professional patent translator, you will find no better translation.

---

**Footnote**

[1](https://www.deepl.com/translator/files) A research paper entitled "[Validation of the Reliability of Machine Translation for a Medical Article From Japanese to English Using DeepL Translator](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8494522/pdf/cureus-0013-00000017778.pdf)" by Takakusagi Y, Oike T, Shirai K, et al. (September 06, 2021) . Cureus 13(9): e17778. DOI 10.7759/cureus.17778 found that “[t]he translation for a medical article from Japanese to English was performed accurately by DeepL Translator.” (see page 1., subtitled “Conclusion”)

[2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8494522/pdf/cureus-0013-00000017778.pdf) I replaced the .docx to a .pdf as DeepL (using Adobe) doesn't seem to reconstruct .docx files as good as .pdf files.